# The document could not be opened for editing in SP 2010 with MS Office Professional Plus 2010 64-bit

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am working on Sharepoint Foundation 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit; 
I have a Sharepoint site with document library. 
upload Microsoft word documents, when I select one of them and click on "Edit in Microsoft Word" then I got an ERROR 
"The document could not be opened for editing. A Microsoft SharePoint Foundation compatible application could not be found to edit the document. " 
I have already installed MS Office Professional Plus 2010 64-bit on my machine.. 
Please let me know what is the problem and how to resolve this...

All add-ons regarding SharePoint "ENABLED" in browser but alas not succeeded

In Chrome/Firefox receive error message "The document could not be opened for editing. A Microsoft SharePoint Foundation compatible application could not be found to edit the document. "

But In IE10 while trying to open an excel document stored in "Documents Library", the excel application opens up with a login prompt, to which I passed the login credentials of the site. After which the excel shows an error

"Could not open 'serverName/sites/MyPortal/HR Documents/Attendence Sheet.xlsx'"
The same is the case for word documents too. I am running SharePoint 2010 on windows 7 64-bit and MS Office 2010 Professional plus 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have above, there could be a number of issues at play.

SharePoint 2010 integration with IE relies on an ActiveX control that comes bundled with MS Office to work, however the x64 version of office does not install them.  You may have a previous edition of these plugins loaded, which is causing issues with IE.

You may also want to look at your local configuration for how extensions are mapped and ensure they are mapped to the appropriate office application.

Try to disable office integration for the web application and test again?  Does the behavior change?  All browsers should just prompt you to download the application then it should start it locally based on your default program configuration.

Also, try using the 32bit version of office.  Generally speaking, you don't need to run x64 version of office, the only app that really benefits is Excel, and then only with large complex workbooks. Microsoft recommends running 32 bit version due to comparability issues with other software.  Bear in mind however you can't run 32 and 64 bit office application side by side, you need to completely remove 64bit version of office. If you previously had 32 bit then went 64 bit,this could what is causing your issues as well depending on what may have been left over from a previous installation.

If you really want to dig down into, you need to run ProcMon, and see what is happening with the request when it tries to open an Office Application.  It will list out all file and registry requests for you to track down the failure.